# How to remove the focus of the back stack fragment?

Tags: android, focus, fragment, onresume

I am using fragments in my application.I have a fragment that contains `EditText` and some `Dialogfragment`.

When i click one particular widget it will move to next fragment. I need the first fragment in the backstack,so i added addToBackStack method also.

The second fragment doesn't contain any `EditText`. Now the problem is, when we touch or press the second fragment, `EditText` in the first fragment get the focus and the dialogs are coming.

I got the following code

```
getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
getView().requestFocus();
```

I placed this in `onResume()`. But `onResume()` will not be called according to  some android documents. What I should I do? This is the picture  of the second activity that shows the problem
             [image]

Comment: @user2894326 which library u have used for this design

Comment: i didn't use any libraries

Comment: u want to hide your keyboard when you call 1 fragment to another fragment? @user2894326

Comment: no.This is second fragment that have no edittext. and the keyboard is not showing while moving from first to second.problem is without editexts and it shows like editext get focus and while touching the alert dialogs are showing (these alert dialogs should populate in first fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my question is instead of adding the fragment just use replace and one more thing we can avoid that by giving click to the layout also

Comment: No, replace cause many scenarios to you to handle them. Better try my above answer. Your giving the alternative not the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*From your question I understood that your* **Current Fragment doesn't have focus**

***Try Following***

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInnstance) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
```